# Como quebrar (split) strings e colocar resultado em variáveis separadas?

Tags: java, variáveis

```
public class Teste30 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String teste = "Isso funciona mesmo, ok?";
        String [] vetor = teste.split(" ");

        String aqui = null;
        String ali = null;
        String acola;
        String there;

        aqui = vetor[0];
        ali = vetor[1];
        acola = vetor[3];
            there = vetor[4];
        }
        for(String nome : vetor){
            System.out.println(nome);

        }
    }
```

Gostaria de saber se tem uma forma não tão braçal de incluir essas `String`s partidas nas variáveis que guardam esse valor.

Comment: Mas porque essa forma não te agrada?

Comment: Para responder se tem uma forma menos braçal, depende muito do que você quer fazer. O seu código por exemplo, não deixa claro qual foi o motivo pelo qual ele foi quebrado assim, vez que `aqui`, `ali`, `acola` e `there` não são usadas em lugar nenhum. Além disso, este código não compila, pois há um fecha-chaves a mais (ou então o `for` apenas foi parar fora do método) e também, `testelista` não está declarado em lugar nenhum. Explique melhor o que você quer fazer com as `String`s obtidas do `split(" ")`, que daí vai dar para responder alguma coisa.

Comment: Por curiosidade, qual o motivo de não usá-las de dentro do vetor já gerado acessando através dos índices?

Comment: Além disso, dê uma olhada no [problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132), pois eu acho que a sua questão é um caso deste problema (embora eu possa estar errado).

Comment: @Wilker sin verdade vou fazer dessa forma como vc  citou. Muito obrigada

Comment: Sei lá @LocalHost vai que exista uma forma melhor para escrever esse código. Imagine que preciso quebrar String e o resultado seja para guardar 40 posições em um array. Para eu utilizar esses valores é só usar direto pelo indice do array mesmo?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Pode acessar diretamente pelo índice do array.

Comment: Entendi...OK! Vou ecrever assim.

Comment: Se fosse PHP, daria para usar "extract", mas em java, ou em qualquer outra linguagem compilada, não há algo similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem como simplificar.

Nesse exemplo a forma menos braçal é não fazer essa atribuição para essas variáveis. Elas não estão sendo usadas e mesmo que forem usadas em uma continuação do código, pra que? Use as próprias variáveis do vetor.

Se tiver que criar as variáveis mesmo, declare a atribua de uma só vez.

Variáveis são locais de armazenamento de memória com um nome, nada mais que isto. Porque armazenar um valor em algum lugar com um nome? Normalmente porque precisa usar ele mais de uma vez. Ou se precisa fazer vários passos com aquele valor que não podem ser colocados juntos. Também pode ser quando está fazendo algo muito complexo e quer documentar melhor, mas isso já é menos comum.

Pra que criar variáveis sem necessidade? Toda vez que não conseguir explicar o motivo de existir uma variável, elimine-a. Essa "regrinha" básica já ajuda. É claro que a pessoa ainda pode dar explicações sem sentido.

O código simplificado que faz a mesma coisa (o código nem compilava na forma escrita):

```
class Teste30 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String nome : "Isso funciona mesmo, ok?".split(" ")) System.out.println(nome);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EZBFBy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/aiaabhtg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/SplitPhrase.java).

Mas se ainda quiser criar essas variáveis soltas para uso posterior:

```
class Teste30 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String teste = "Isso funciona mesmo, ok?";
        String[] vetor = teste.split(" ");
        String aqui = vetor[0];
        String ali = vetor[1];
        String acola = vetor[3];
        String there = vetor[4];
        for (String nome : vetor) System.out.println(nome);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ExPaxl). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vuepadwq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/SplitPhrase2.java).